# How do I find an activity indicator in a UITableViewCell on completion of multiple UIWebView requests?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiwebview

I am pretty new to Objective-C and iOS programming.

I have a `SummaryUITableViewCell` (a custom class inheriting from `UITableViewCell`) which contains an Activity Indicator (`loadingSpinner`) and a UIWebView (`webView`).

My app gets a list of URLs to load, then presents the table view, one cell per URL.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I start the animation for the loading spinner and call `cell.webView loadRequest:URL`.

Everything works fine and `webViewDidFinishLoad` gets called once per URL (it has just an `NSLog` statement in it for now). What I can't figure out is how to find the appropriate `loadingSpinner` so that I can stop the animation and hide it.

Comment: Each cell should be its own web view delegate, then it can simply stop its own loading spinner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want each of your `SummaryUITableViewCell` to implement `UIWebViewDelegate` and handle the `webViewDidFinishLoad` call themselves. Then you can easily hide the spinners each time the `UIWebView` loads. Here is one way you could implement the `SummaryUITableViewCell`.

SummaryTableViewCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SummaryTableViewCell : UITableViewCell <UIWebViewDelegate>

@end
```

SummaryTableViewCell.m

```
#import "SummaryTableViewCell.h"

@interface SummaryTableViewCell ()

// Keep references to our spinner and webview here
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *webView;

@end

@implementation SummaryTableViewCell

- (instancetype)initWithUrl:(NSString *)url {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setup:url];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setup:(NSString *)url {
    // Add Webview
    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[self frame]];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
    [self.webView setAlpha:0];

    // Set the cell as the delegate of the webview
    [self.webView setDelegate:self];
    [self addSubview:self.webView];

    // Add Spinner
    self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];
    [self addSubview:self.spinner];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    // The web view loaded the url so we can now hide the spinner and show the web view
    [self.spinner setAlpha:0];
    [self.webView setAlpha:1];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is basically how I did it, except only one `[super init]` (I presume that was a typo) and the webVirew allocation etc. are in the table view controller, with the webView delegate set to cell